# Solving sextic polynomials with modular forms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, modular-forms

A very long time ago, I made a since removed post about solving higher order polynomials. This post demonstrated the radical solutions for degrees $1$ to $4$ and also some solutions for higher degree polynomials with less familiar functions. It was intended to be far reaching while still being comprehensible by a beginner. However, there was $1$ formula I knew that didn't quite fit this bill. I tried to include it anyway, which led to the post being controversial and somewhat hated for involving higher functions at the end while still supposedly being beginner oriented. Therefore, I think it makes sense to make a separate post discussing this formula and how it might be generalized. $$x^{6}+10x^{3}+cx+5=0,\ x=\frac{5η\left(5j^{-1}\left(-c^{3}\right)\right)^{2}}{η\left(j^{-1}\left(-c^{3}\right)\right)^{2}}$$ This formula solves a special sextic using modular forms, and I started wondering. Could there be a general sextic formula in modular forms using a similar approach? If so, how so? I'm not entirely sure if I tagged this properly, kinda hard to tell since I haven't really seen anything like this before. I honestly don't even understand how I knew this back then. It's like it dropped out of the sky.

Comment: By "**full** sextic formula" do you mean the **general** sextic $ax^6+bx^5+cx^4+\cdots$ ? Maybe with $a=1$ ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://cpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/sites.psu.edu/dist/d/34699/files/2015/09/PolynomialsDraft3.pdf).

Comment: This is equivalent to a Dedekind $\eta$ product identity. Let $u_1:=\eta(\tau), u_2:=\eta(2\tau), u_5:=\eta(5\tau).$ Then $u_5^2(u_1^{24} + 256u_2^{24}) = u_1^6u_2^8(u_1^{12} + 250u_1^6u_5^6 + 3125u_5^{12}).$

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah that's what I meant. I'm not good with jargon but I have the concepts down. At least, I usually do. This formula still makes no sense to me. Would be nice to include a by the way, since it's trivial to reduce $ax^{6}+bx^{5}+cx^{4}+dx^{3}+ex^{2}+fx+g=0$ to $x^{6}+Bx^{5}+Cx^{4}+Dx^{3}+Ex^{2}+Fx+G=0$

Comment: This topic is way over my knowledge but it is indeed interesting. How can we go about finding the roots uisng the formula for $x$? What is $η$?

Comment: @NoChance That is the Dedekind eta function. I'm not entirely sure what the numerical algorithm for this function is, but I prefer to just leave the answer in exact form regardless. I assume you're talking about the numerical algorithm anyway, it's not very clear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Maybe I get to understand this stuff one day...

Comment: @NoChance Tbh I don't have the best comprehension of this formula either. I know what it is, but the process of deriving it as described by El Rafu genuinely doesn't make the slightest sense to me.

Comment: @BabyHeartyBear Which part? I can perhaps elaborate more.
Regarding your other question, I don't think your formula works for a general sextic, because the closed solution requires the root $x$ to be related to $j$ (which in turn is related to your constant $c$) in a particularly nice way. One way to see how you get this particular eta quotient is to realise that the second equation in the answer is a defining equation for $x(\tau)^3$ as the Hauptmodul for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(5)$, whose expression as an eta-quotient is known.

Comment: If on the other hand $j=R(x)$ with $R$ a "generic" rational function then $x$ is not a modular function for any subgroup of $SL(2,Z)$ in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$P(x)=^6+10^3+(-j)^{\frac13}+5$$
Then $P(x)=0$ can be solved for $j$ as
$$j=\frac{\left(x^6+10 x^3+5\right)^3}{x^3}.$$
We can now lift both $j$ and $x$ to be functions of $\tau\in\mathbb H$, with $j$ the modular $j$-function. We can expand $j$ around $x=0$ and invert the series order by order. Inserting the $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$-expansion of $j$, one finds
$$x(\tau)=5q^{\frac13}(1+2 q+5 q^2+10 q^3+20 q^4+...),$$
which agrees with the Fourier expansion of the inverse of the McKay-Thompson series of class 15D for the Monster group. Thus
$$x(\tau)=5\left(\frac{\eta(5\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}\right)^2.$$
By defining $c=(-j(\tau_c))^{\frac13}$, $P(x(\tau_c))=0$ has then one root  $x(\tau_c)=5\left(\frac{\eta(5\tau_c)}{\eta(\tau_c)}\right)^2$.

Comment: It is hard to see how you assumed $j$ was the $j$ invariant for this very specific polynomial. Also, how did you “expand $j$ around $x=0$ and invert the series order by order”; maybe it is a Taylor or Fourier series for the inverse of the polynomial?

Comment: If $f$ is a modular function for a finite index subgroup $\Gamma$ of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, then it is the zero of a polynomial over the field of modular functions on $\Gamma$, whose degree is the index of $\Gamma$ in $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. The above solution is just anticipating this fact. So for $j$ you could choose any other $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ invariant function also.

Comment: Indeed, you consider $j$ as a meromorphic function in $x$ and Laurent expand it around $x=0$. This allows to locally invert this relation.